# AngularJS weird behaviour with $resource and $httpBackend

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-resource

I have following AngularJS resource exposed as a service

```
 myServices.factory('Service1', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {

        var Registrations = $resource('/api/v1/registration/:id');

        return {
            getForTcn: function(tcn) {
                return Registrations.query({ tcn: tcn, state: 'Active' }).$promise;
            }

        };
    } ]);
```

And I have a Jasmine test which fails below

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, Service1) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    service = Service1;

    $httpBackend.when('GET', /^\/api\/v1\/registration\?.*/).respond([]);
}));afterEach(function () {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

With above setup below assertion fails

```
it('should have correct http GET request', function () {
    Service.getForTcn('1234');
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/v1/registration?tcn=1234&State=Active');
    $httpBackend.flush();
});
```

If I swap the places of the parameters in the service function and in the assertion the test passes.

```
getForTcn: function(tcn) {
                return Registrations.query({ state: 'Active', tcn: tcn }).$promise;
            }
$httpBackend.expectGET('/api/v1/registration?state=Active&tcn=1234');
```

Any idea what's going on here?
I haven't tried if the version that's failing actually works when executed outside test but has anyone seen similar behaviour?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the query arguments are arranged alphabetically so if you had `foo` as an argument then your assertion would be:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('/api/v1/registration?foo=1234&state=Active');
```

and this would pass. Conversely if the argument was `zoo` then the assertion would be:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('/api/v1/registration?state=Active&zoo=1234');
```

which is why you have to put `tcn` after the `state` argument as you indicate in your question.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent AngularJS to sort the parameters so that the order of parameters remain as they are passed to the action?